# Laravel alias column name in Eloquent model

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model

How can I alias a column name in a model? I would like to show `idUser` instead of id in API responses. So far I've tried the following.

```php
protected $maps = [
    'id' => 'idUser',
];

protected $visible = [
    'idUser'
];

protected $appends = [
    'idUser'
];
```

This gives me an error:

> 'Call to undefined method App\User::getIdUserAttribute()'

Also, I would like to alias created_at and updated_at to createdAt and updatedAt.

Comment: Are you using API resources or do you return plain arrays or models? With API resources, renaming is straight forward.

Answer (score 2):

you can define accessor method in your model like this :

```
public function getUserIdAttribute($)
{
    return $this->id;
}
```

and then you have to add the attribute name in the `$appends` array

```
protected $appends = ['user_id'];
```

for more details checkout the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json)

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators

Comment: question. If you do this, can you modify fillable using the alias? I'm looking at a use case where I could use a single 'abstract' model type for user details for buyer vs. seller vs. shipping address. so id could be aliased to buyer_user_id (used for both buyer and shipment) or seller_user_id depending on the incoming rest data.

Answer (score 1):

As @Namoshek's comment, you should be able to return a custom aliases for each column by renaming it.

First, look for which route you want to edit in folder `routes/api.php`. You can either use callback function or a Controller to manage the response.

```
// routes/api.php
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('auth/retrieve-user', function(Request $request) {
    $user = Auth::user();

    return response()
        ->json([
            'userId' => $user->id,
            'createdAt' => $user->created_at,
            'updatedAt' => $user->updated_at,
        ]);
});
```